# get client port number from server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

There's a way to get the client port through the rails server, on controller?

I know which is possible to get the remote ip by **request.remote_ip**, but I need something like request.remote_port.

Comment: Are you refering to the port the server is listening on? That one you get with ``request.port``

Comment: If you put `<%= request.methods %>` in one of your views you can easily see a list of all the available methods.

Comment: Why do you need to know the remote port?

Comment: @dgilperez I need the client port.

Comment: @Stefan I have two machines in different NATs, I need to know what port the NATs used to communicate with server.

Comment: @ptd thanks for the answer, maybe I find what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Rack's [Hijacking](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/file/SPEC#Hijacking) feature exposes the underlying Socket or IO object.

Here's an example using [Puma](http://puma.io), it returns a [`TCPSocket`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCSocket.html):

```
if request.env['rack.hijack?']
  request.env['rack.hijack'].call
  io = request.env['rack.hijack_io']
  io.class    #=> TCPSocket
  io.addr     #=> ["AF_INET", 3000, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]
  io.peeraddr #=> ["AF_INET", 51464, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]
end
```